# PHP Websocket client + ssl

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, client

There is a PHP Websocket client: https://github.com/symbiose/php-websocket-client repository. And it works fine for not-secured connection.

What I need is to connect to a websocket server from php code through secure connection. To implement this task I took the code above and modified it a bit. The connect() method of WebSocketClient now looks like this in my code:

```
public function connect()
{
    $root = $this;
    if ($this->getPort() == 443) {
      $context = stream_context_create();
      stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
      stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
      $client = stream_socket_client("tls://{$this->getHost()}:{$this->getPort()}", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
    } else {
      $client = stream_socket_client("tcp://{$this->getHost()}:{$this->getPort()}", $errno, $errstr);
    }
    if (!$client) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Cannot connect to socket ([#'.$errno.'] '.$errstr.')');
    }
    $this->setSocket(new Connection($client, $this->getLoop()));
    $this->getSocket()->on('data', function ($data) use ($root) {
        $data = $root->parseIncomingRaw($data);
        $root->parseData($data);
    });
    $this->getSocket()->write($this->createHeader());
    return $this;
}
```

As a result I almost managed to connect to a server. Websocket server saw my connection, replied that everything is ok and wrote it to the log.

But unfortunately, the library doesn't understand, that it has successfully connected to the server.

This "if":

```
    if (base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($this->key . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'))) === $response['Sec-Websocket-Accept']) {
        $this->connected = true;
    }
```

never gets executed. And so I can't establish the connection.

I can also confirm, that if we use 80 port - everything works like a charm.

So if you have any ideas on why this can happen, i"d really really appreciate them. Cause I've already ran out of ideas.

Best regards,
Kostya

Comment: Maybe it's too late, but did you check "context SSL Options"->"local_cert" by adding your xxx.pem certificate to the context?